# Convert symbol in Classname::FunctionName( Para1, Para2 )

Tags: c++, gcc, name-mangling

I'm using the GNU extension "`char** backtrace_symbols(void *buffer, int size)`" to get the stack trace, when an exception is thrown. Is there a library function which converts the symbol into a "human readable" string - to redo the name mangling?

If not, I would write my own function according to this [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Complex_example).

Concrete:

```
Input:  test.exe(_ZN10CTLTestApp12ExecuteGroupEPK19CTLTestCaseRegisterNS_11EReportTypeE+0x24c) 
Output: test.exe CTLTestApp::ExecuteGroup( CTLTestCaseRegister, EReportType )
```

Thanks a lot,

Charly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <cxxabi.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
  int status;
  const std::string name = "_ZN10CTLTestApp12ExecuteGroupEPK19CTLTestCaseRegisterNS_11EReportTypeE";
  char *realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(name.c_str(), 0, 0, &status);
  std::cout << realname << "(" << status << ")" << std::endl;
  free(realname);
}
```

Running gives:

```
CTLTestApp::ExecuteGroup(CTLTestCaseRegister const*, CTLTestApp::EReportType)(0)
```

See the online [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) for a more complete example and further details on this.

Comment: I seem to recall seeing a library somewhere that offered this on several different platforms though, but I can't find the link again.